# Rails 4: Forcing specific values with "strong parameters"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm struggling with a form for creating "Projects". Eventually I want to allow only the current user_id but I haven't built the User model or authentication yet so as a placeholder, I'm just hard-coding `1`.

app/views/projects/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for(:project, :url => {:action=>'create'}) do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field(:name) %>
<%= f.text_field(:instructions) %>
<%= f.hidden_field( :user_id, {:value=>1}) %>
<%= f.submit('Create Project') %>
<% end %>
```

app/controllers/projects_controller.rb

```
  def create
    #save object
    if Project.create( project_params )
        redirect_to(:action=>'show')
    else
        render('new')
    end
  end

  private
    def project_params
      params.require(:project).permit({:user_id => [1]}, :instructions, :max_duration, :active, :max_videos, :hashed_id)
    end
```

Here's the error I get when I try to submit the form:

```
Mysql2::Error: Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value: INSERT INTO `projects` (`created_at`, `instructions`, `updated_at`) VALUES ('2013-08-16 17:38:56', 'sdfgsdf', '2013-08-16 17:38:56')
```

It appears that the project_params() method is stripping out the user_id. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try with only `{:user_id => 1}` (just a Integer, not an array) or eventually take off the user_id part and add after the permit: 
`.permit(:instructions, :etc).merge!({user_id: 1})`

Comment: Yeh, or `f.hidden_field(:user_id, 1)`

Comment: @Edmund a hidden_field is still *very easy* to change. It is better to set it after the user's input on the server side.

Comment: @MrYoshiji it makes sense that I should be permitting an integer (not an array), but it's still throws the missing field error with: `{:user_id=>1}` or `{:user_id=>'1'}`

Comment: Have you tried merging the Hash `{user_id: 1}` to the params Hash?

Comment: @MrYoshiji Yes. It works with the merge, but I still want to figure out why it doesn't work inside the `permit()`

Comment: Oh I think I got it: `.permit(user_id: [1])` will only accepts a value of 1 for the params[:user_id], but you didn't send it via your form. (see exemples: http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit)

Comment: With `.permit(user_id: [1,5,7])` function you only permit the params[:user] to contain a key `user_id` which can be equal to 1,5 or 7. It does not add the user_id to the params hash if not present.

Comment: @MrYoshiji Can you explain why it is not sent from my form? Is this not correct: `<%= f.hidden_field( :user_id, {:value=>1}) %>`

Comment: Oh, strange ... I didn't see that hidden field. So your params[:user] contains a value equal to 1 for the key `user_id`, right?

Comment: @MrYoshiji I think my params[:project] contains a value equal to 1 for the key `user_id`.

Comment: @Emerson probably is because params[:user_id] equals to "1", is a string and is expecting an integer .. try `.permit(user_id: ["1"])` to see if it works

Comment: Oh yea right params[:project], sorry. Can you post the output of the project_params and params ? Use `raiser [params, project_params]` in the create action

Comment: @MrYoshiji raiser throws an undefined method error. Is there another easy way to debug the params array?

Answer (score 1):

probably is because params[:user_id] is a string, doing something like this should work.

```
params.require(:project).permit({:user_id => ["1"]}, :instructions, :max_duration, :active, :max_videos, :hashed_id)
```

Comment: Looks like it does not work in latest Rails (at least starting from version 4.1) --> https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters/issues/167